# Jenkins Configuration Slicing plugin with Cloudbees Folders plugin

Tags: plugins, jenkins, directory, cloudbees

Has anyone had success using these two plugins together?

The Configuration Slicing plugin allows you to filter jobs using views but it cannot see jobs within Folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cfcd3d0](https://github.com/jenkinsci/configurationslicing-plugin/commit/cfcd3d0f6aec34035e773d656d1991aa45a8061c) in 1.37 claims to fix this. (There seems to be a follow-up fix, [eefdd37](https://github.com/jenkinsci/configurationslicing-plugin/commit/eefdd378edd33db54ec7e2abcddbc63ca7428fec).) If that does not do it for you, file a bug in the plugin for tracking, with the label `folders`. [JENKINS-16329](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16329) is already open though it has not been updated since that fix.